# Saving position of each button in array after dragging

Tags: ios, objective-c, custom-keyboard

I need some serious help. I am building keyboard app in objective c, and one of the features I have is to drag keyboard buttons around the keyboard screen so that user can place them in any place. But my problem is that I can't figure out how to save each button position after dragging so that when user switches off and then on all keyboard buttons are in the same place where user placed them before.

My code is as per below:

This is in my viewDidLoad:

```
for (UIButton *button in self.allButtonsArray) {
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                        initWithTarget:self
                                                        action:@selector(handlePanGestureButtons:)];

        [button addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];

    }
```

Method for handling pan:

```
(void) handlePanGestureButtons:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

    NSString *_valueOfDragging= [defaults stringForKey:@"stateOfSwitchButtonDragging"];

    if([_valueOfDragging compare:@"ON"] == NSOrderedSame){

        if (gesture.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged || gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
            UIView *superview = gesture.view.superview;
            CGSize superviewSize = superview.bounds.size;
            CGSize thisSize = gesture.view.frame.size;
            CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:self.view];
            CGPoint center = CGPointMake(gesture.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                         gesture.view.center.y + translation.y);

            CGPoint resetTranslation = CGPointMake(translation.x, translation.y);

            if(center.x - thisSize.width/2 < 0)
                center.x = thisSize.width/2;
            else if (center.x + thisSize.width/2 > superviewSize.width)
                center.x = superviewSize.width-thisSize.width/2;
            else
                resetTranslation.x = 0;

            if(center.y - thisSize.height/2 < 0)
                center.y = thisSize.height/2;
            else if(center.y + thisSize.height/2 > superviewSize.height)
                center.y = superviewSize.height-thisSize.height/2;
            else
                resetTranslation.y = 0; //Only reset the vertical translation if the view *did* translate vertically

            gesture.view.center = center;
            [gesture setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store all your coordinates in `NSUserDefaults`, which you can access again when you open your app. Since coordinates are `CGPoint` values, you need to convert them first to string objects using `NSStringFromCGPoint`. You can then create an array with the coordinates for all your buttons and write them to your user defaults. To be able to identify each button, you can make an array of structs, for instance:

```
struct KeyCoordinate {
    NSString *keyIdentifier;
    NSString *keyCoordinate;
}

struct KeyCoordinate keyCoordinate1;
struct KeyCoordinate keyCoordinate2;

keyCoordinate1.keyIdentifier = @"key1"
keyCoordinate1.keyCoordinate = NSStringFromCGPoint(key1Point);
keyCoordinate2.keyIdentifier = @"key2"
keyCoordinate2.keyCoordinate = NSStringFromCGPoint(key2Point);

NSArray *buttonCoordinatesArray = @[keyCoordinate1, keyCoordinate2, ...];

NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// write:
[userDefaults setObject: buttonCoordinatesArray forKey: @"buttonCoordinatesArray"];

// read:
NSArray *buttonCoordinatesArray = [userDefaults objectForKey: @"buttonCoordinatesArray"];
```

To revert from strings to points use `CGPointFromString`.

Alternatively you can store the points as `NSValue` in your struct, but the idea remains the same.

Comment: Thank You very much. I managed to save CGPoint in user defaults, but when I am trying to apply saved position after app is closed and the opened it still appears in the same old place. I duing this:  NSString *stringPosition = [defaults stringForKey: @"viewPosition"];
        CGPoint position = CGPointFromString(stringPosition);
        NSLog(@"Saved Position: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(position));
        allView.center = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(position, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1));
        NSLog(@"Center Position: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(allView.center));

Comment: Can it be because I am using constraits which have higher priority? Or I am doing something wrong. Because when I am doing the same with rotation, line in the below code it works perfectly. CGFloat rotation = [defaults floatForKey:@"rotationAngle"];
        allViews.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation);

Comment: Possible, maybe you can see if you can also store the constraints in userDefaults?

Comment: But is this line of code correct, because I somehow feel that the problem is here. allView.center = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(position, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1));

Comment: What is it supposed to do, and what do you actually observe? When/where are you calling that line?

Comment: I am calling this line in init method and this method gets called in viewDidLoad. This line should place my view in the position(CGPoint) which was previously saved in user defaults. Nothing happens also when I try to do it simply like in the code below. NSString *stringPosition = [defaults stringForKey: @"viewPosition"];
        CGPoint position = CGPointFromString(stringPosition);
        NSLog(@"Saved Position: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(position));
        allView.center = position;

Comment: But the fact is that it is saved correctly because when I am printing it in log NSLog(@"Saved Position: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(position)); it show me correct previous position.

Comment: Try adding `[allView setNeedsDisplay];` after updating the coordinates.

Comment: I suppose I found the problem. When I am setting [self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO]; in viewDidLayoutSubviews method, then everything is saving properly but at the same time it disables absolutely everything like dragging buttons, rotation and even simple button pressing... I think it is conflicting with constraints which I already have and constraints have higher priority.

Comment: If you still have problems, I recommend to start a new question about the updating issue.